# How to add string objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray named randomSelection:

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection;
```

I am then trying to add strings to this array if certain criteria are met:

```
[randomSelection addObject:@"string1"];
```

I am then trying to output the string, to determine if it has added it:

```
NSString *test = [randomSelection objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(test);
```

However nothing is being output to the error log and I can't figure out why.

Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the certain critera to add the string are met? Otherwise, maybe you should try NSLog(@"%@", test);

Comment: Yes the criteria is met. 

Just below NSLog(test) i have placed: NSLog("Made It!"); and that is being displayed.

Comment: do i need to initialise the NSMutable array and alocate with ample space or something? I thought that was the point of this addObject function so that i dont have to do that.

Comment: @David Brunow Please read question before putting any comments or ans.... this guy had not allocate "NSMutableArray *randomSelection;", so how he expect to get array object....

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think you are missing to allocate the memory for array. So try this

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[randomSelection addObject:@"string1"];
NSString *test = [randomSelection objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(test);
```

Comment: @SamBo did indeed forget to allocate memory and initialize it. Right now the Array gets declared, but not defined.

Comment: @ophychius Also had the same problem. At least now I know that I need to allocate memory for the array first. But isn't there a more generic way to specify that you only want to add strings in the array?

Answer (score 5):

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[randomSelection addObject:@"string1"];
```

You need to alloc it first.

Comment: Worked for me..Thank you buddy..:)

Answer (score 2):

First allocate the array using following statement & then objects in it.

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[randomSelection addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"String1"]];
[randomSelection addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"String2"]];
NSLog(@"Array - %@", randomSelection);
```

This will definitely solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
[randomSelection addObject:@"string1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just allocate your NSMutableArray. You'll get solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift :**

```
var randomSelection: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
randomSelection.append("string1")
let test: String = randomSelection[0] as! String
print(test)
```

OR

```
let array : NSMutableArray = []
array.addObject("test String")
print(array)
```