# string array value to NSMutableArray in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string retrieving from sqlite

```
({ 
    studentId = SUE1291ST;
    studentName = "Student123Sdfw"; 
  }, 
  { 
    studentId = SUE13291ST;
    studentName = "name123Sdfw";
 })
```

how to convert to `NSMutableArray` and to get `NSDictionary`.... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834390/how-to-add-string-objects-to-nsmutablearray

Comment: google for "json parse ios" and u will get alot of help. https://www.google.com.pk/#q=json+parser+ios&spell=1

Comment: It seems that you used the `description` method to convert an NSArray into a string and store that into the SQLite database. There is no *reliable* way to reconstruct the array/dictionary from the description string (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16783704/1187415 for an *unreliable* method). You should store the dictionary in a different way, e.g. in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is json (as your tags suggest) the easiest way is to use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Using

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

Will get you a foundation class object returned (NSArray, NSDictionary, depending on the json data)

Comment: it is not a json.it is a string value from sqlite db

Comment: @user2775424 then why do you use the json tag? Google "NSString parsing", it will tell you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
u want dict values from array..so

 dataArray =[NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dic setObject:@"SUE1291ST" forKey:@"studentId"];
    [dic setObject:@"Student123Sdfw" forKey:@"studentName"];

    [dataArray addObject:dic];

     dic =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dic setObject:@"SUE13291ST" forKey:@"studentId"];
    [dic setObject:@"name123Sdfw" forKey:@"studentName"];

    [dataArray addObject:dic];

    NSLog(@"dataArray:%@",dataArray);

    for (NSDictionary *dic in dataArray) {

        NSLog(@"DICTIONARY IS:%@",dic);
    }
```